# My Vue.js code about Axios and function is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I want to execute **function2** after axios. I got no catch error. but still Function2 is not executed.

**The code i want but not working :**

```
   add: function () {
        axios.post('/add', this.person)
            .then(response => {
               if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.person = {};
                    this.function2();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })},
```

This is working, but i would like to execute function2 only if axios pass.

```
add: function () {
        axios.post('/add', this.person)
            .then(response => {
               if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.person = {};

                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
             this.function2();
             },
```

Any help ? thank you !

Comment: what  does `response.data.etat` return?

Comment: Nothing.. but my axios pass and my data is sent to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain .then() blocks:

```
add: function () {
        axios.post('/add', this.person)
            .then(response => {
               if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.person = {};
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
               this.function2();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
}
```

`this.function2` will be called only if your axios.post is successful and if the first `.then()` doesn't throw any error. In another case - your `.catch()` will catch the error.

Here you can see how it works on live:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZQyym?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using axios to post data, and you want to do call that method after the operation is done successfully so you should check the response status like :

```
   add: function () {
    axios.post('/add', this.person)
        .then(response => {
           if (response.status==200) {
                this.person = {};
                this.function2();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('errors: ', error)
        })},
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest ! Btw I'm Y.J

Comment: :)  i guessed that